# Interpolation of two inequalities

Tags: interpolation, interpolation-theory

Let $X_0,X_1,Y_0,Y_1$ be Banach spaces and $T \colon (X_0+X_1) \times (Y_0+Y_1) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$| T(f,g) | \le \| f\|_{X_0} \|g\|_{Y_0}$$
and
$$| T(f,g) | \le \| f\|_{X_1} \|g\|_{Y_1} + C_1$$
for some constant $C_2>0$. We may assume that $T$ is bilinear.

I am interested in whether one can interpolate these two inequalities in the sense that
$$| T(f,g) | \le \| f\|_{X_\theta} \|g\|_{Y_\theta} + C_2$$
for some constant $C_2>0$, where $X_\theta,Y_\theta$ are suitable interpolation spaces between $X_0,X_1$ and $Y_0,Y_1$ respectively.

Comment: By a simple scaling argument, it is clear that we can choose $C_1 = 0$ in the second inequality.

Comment: I am sorry but I don’t understand your comment. Can you please elaborate that a little bit.

Comment: Since $T$ is bilinear, we have $|T(f,g)| = 1/n |T(nf, g)| \le \|f\| \|g\| + C_1 / n$. Now you can pass to the limit $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks I understand. You may aswell add this comment as an answer. The rest is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a simple scaling argument, it is clear that we can choose $C_1 = 0$ in the second inequality. Indeed,
since $T$ is bilinear, we have $|T(f,g)| = 1/n |T(nf, g)| \le \|f\| \|g\| + C_1 / n$. Now you can pass to the limit $n \to \infty$.

The rest is clear.